# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre #!/usr/bin/python y #!/usr/bin/env python?

Tags: python, unix

He visto que muchas veces se usan estas lineas `#!/usr/bin/python` y `#!/usr/bin/env python` al comienzo de los scripts y me preguntaba si había alguna diferencia, de haberla, ¿cual es más recomendable usar?

Comment: No es una pregunta específica de python. El uso de `env` es para hacer más portable el script entre distintos unixen ya que el ejecutable no siempre está en el mismo sitio.

Comment: si bien no es especifica tampoco es excluyente : D !!

Comment: No era una crítica. Seguramente haya mucha gente que llegue a esta pregunta buscando por `python` y eso es lo importante. (BTW, he añadido la etiqueta `unix` para que quede más claro).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### #!/usr/bin/env python

Yo diría que esta es la más recomendable ya que hace uso del entorno para buscar la primera ocurrencia del ejecutable de Python . Si lees la documentación del comando `env`:

```
$ man env
ENV(1)

NAME
       env - run a program in a modified environment
...
```

Se entiende que ejecutas un comando en un entorno modificado. Veamos que hay en el `$PATH`:

```
$ env
...
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/cesar/Development/Android/android-sdk-linux/platform_tools:/home/cesar/Development/Android/android-sdk-linux/tools
...
```

Entonces al usar `#!/usr/bin/env python` buscará el ejecutable del comando `python` de acuerdo a las rutas definidas en el `$PATH` de tu entorno, esto es bueno ya que es posible que tengas instaladas varias versiones de Python (en Linux normalmente tienes la version 2 y 3).

Si probamos esto en la terminal (el resultado puede variar):

```
$ env python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Para demostrar el funcionamiento de `env` vamos a hacer unas pruebas. Creamos un link simbólico de `python3` a `/usr/local/bin`:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Puedes notar más arriba que en mi `$PATH`, la ruta `/usr/local/bin` está antes que la ruta `/usr/bin` por lo que si ejecuto nuevamente:

```
$ env python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:33:09) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Ahora me sale la versión 3 de Python. Observa que pasa si modifico el `$PATH` para efectos de la prueba:

- Con `/usr/bin` como primera ruta:

  ```
  $ PATH="/usr/bin/:/usr/local/bin"
  $ env python
  Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18) 
  [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>>
  ```
- Con `/usr/local/bin` como primera ruta:

  ```
  $ PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"
  $ env python
  Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:33:09) 
  [GCC 4.8.4] on linux
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>>
  ```

Espero que haya quedado claro, creo que es una ventaja usar esta forma pero a veces puede no funcionar como esperas si se han manipulado las rutas de Python, aunque también es posible que seas un poco más específico y uses por ejemplo alguna de estas en tu script:

- `#!/usr/bin/env python2`
- `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

### #!/usr/bin/python

Esta también es válida, simplemente estás llamando a la ruta del ejecutable de Python:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Yo me he topado con algunos problemas con esta forma, creo recordar que en algunas distribuciones de Linux el ejecutable de Python no se encontraba en la ruta `/usr/bin/python`.

### Notas finales

- Se le conoce como [*shebang*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang) al uso de los caracteres `#!` en el inicio de los scripts.
- El *shebang* es reconocido en sistemas de tipo Unix (Linux, Mac), en Windows es simplemente ignorado

Comment: ¡Muy buena respuesta!

Comment: Tienes razón, en Ubuntu cambiaron el directorio de paquetes para python a un directorio local, que locura!

Comment: Al hacer `PATH="/usr/bin/:/usr/local/bin"`, ¿se estaría redefiniendo la variable y ahora `$PATH` solo tendría como valor `"/usr/bin/:/usr/local/bin"`?